# Netty Lag/Latency Simulation

Tags: java, sockets, netty

I'm writing game server with [NETTY](http://netty.io/). I should upload the code to remote server for testing lag/latency problems. But I can't do this every code changes.

How can simulate lag, latency on local network with [NETTY](http://netty.io/)?

Just want to add delay to read/write operations.

Comment: What have you tried and what are you having difficulty with?  What happened when you added a delay to read/write operations. e.g. with `Thread.sleep(10);`

Comment: Use Fiddler to emulate network lags.

Comment: I found "Network Emulater for Windows Toolkit" and It's working great. You can configure everythink (packet loos, latency etc) http://blog.mrpol.nl/2010/01/14/network-emulator-toolkit/